# What does the arrow -> operator do in Ballerina?

Tags: syntax, wso2, ballerina

I'm new to this language and just started back at it after a few months and have a relatively basic question. I'm having some confusion understanding the arrow `->` operator in it. In the examples under [Learn Ballerina By Example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/) the basic `Hello World Main` is described with the code below:

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    io:println("Hello, World!");
}
```

And in the `Hello Word Service` example, the code is as follows:

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/log;

service hello on new http:Listener(9090) {

    resource function sayHello(http:Caller caller, http:Request req) {

        var result = caller->respond("Hello, World!");

        if (result is error) {
            log:printError("Error sending response", result);
        }
    }
}
```

My question lies in the `Hello Word Service` program in the line

```
var result = caller->respond("Hello, World!");
```

I'm from a C/Python/Java background and arrows mean different things in each of these languages. What does it do in Ballerina specifically? I tried to look for the syntax documentation and was unsuccessful in finding it. Any link to the specific page would be helpful too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `->` operator in Ballerina represents a remote interaction. According to the language specification:

> A remote-method-call-action is depicted as a horizontal arrow from the
>   worker lifeline to the client object lifeline.
>
> `remote-method-call-action := expression -> method-name ( arg-list )`

Please refer to the "Remote interaction" section of the language specification below for more information.

https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/2019R3/#section_7.9